# Как правильнее реализовать обработку поискового запроса на таблице

Tags: xcode

Задача такая: на table view есть вверху searchbar и строки таблицы.

мне нужно для поискового запроса по которому нет совпадений из списка вывести сообщение "не найдено" и кнопку "создать свою строку".

у меня есть два варианта решения:

1. использую свою ячейку таблицы:

`numberOfRowsInSection` если строк в итоговом наборе нет - возвращает вместо 0 единицу;

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` соответственно если строк=0 ввожу обработку такой ситуации - все элементы строки скрываю, добавляю надпись и кнопку.

2. если строк=0 то добавляю вьюшку из сториборда на таблицу

   ```
   SearchNoResultViewController * view1 =  [mainStoryboard() instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchNoResultViewController"];
   view1.accessibilityFrame=CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x,self.tableView.frame.origin.y,320,100);
   [self.tableView addSubview:view1.view];
   ```

примерно так.

тут мне пока неясно как оставить searchbar чтобы он работал совместно с отображением вьюшки?

нужно конечно также убирать вьюшку если итог поиска !=0.

мне кажется второй вариант притянутым за уши или так тоже можно делать?

есть еще варианты?

Comment: У Вас строка поиска (`UISearchView`) встроена в `tableHeaderView`?

Comment: да, можно вынести конечно